# Definition of full-expression for init-declarators

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The definition of *full-expression* in the case of an [init-declarator](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.exec#intro.execution-5) is said to "include" the constituent expressions of the initializer, as well as any conversions that are applied/functions that are called implicitly (constructors). This means that a full-expression need not even be an expression, which doesn't make sense because it is referred to as one (an init-declarator is not an expression). Further in the standard, a full expression is used as if it is an expression, so how does that make sense, if it can include disjoint expressions, and things that aren't even expressions?

Anyways, the primary question I have is why full-expressions, which are not always expressions, are treated as being expressions? How is that supposed to work?

Comment: Could you give some examples of code that constitutes a full expression that fits this?

Comment: It can do those things by fiat. That is, it is so because the standard says that it is so. "Full-expression" is a specific term with a specific definition; because of that, the English idea you might get from its component words is irrelevant. A "full-expression" is exactly what the standard says it is. So, what exactly are you interested in understanding here?

Comment: @NicolBolas How full-expressions are referred to as having properties of expression, when they aren't expressions themselves.

For example: [basic.start.static]/2: 
> A constant initializer for a variable or temporary object o is an initializer ***whose full-expression is a constant expression***

Or, how the standard states that full-expressions are evaluated. How can something is might not necessarily be an expression be  evaluated?

Comment: @KrystianS if your question is really about the text you just wrote in the comment, then you should frame your question that way. Otherwise it's not really possible for someone to answer your question in a way that will satisfy you

Comment: @M.M Sorry, I just didn't know how to phrase it until now.

Answer (score 6):

> This means that a full-expression need not even be an expression

Indeed, it does mean that. A full-expression is not necessarily an expression. In the case of init-declarator, it is a declarator.

In earlier version of the standard, a full-expression was specified to be an expression specifically, but that *"certain contexts [...] cause the  evaluation  of  a full-expression that results from a syntactic construct other than expression"*. I haven't read a proposal that suggested change to the wording.

> so how does that make sense

In a convoluted and confusing manner. This is not the only case of ill-fitting nomenclature. Quite similar examples from the standard:

- Member pointers are not pointers
- Default initialisation may leave the object uninitialised

Much like full-expression, these don't make much sense intuitively, but that's how the language is specified regardless.

<sub>I've been listing these in my SO profile, and thanks to this question, I've added a new one.</sub>

Comment: So what does it mean to evaluate a full-expression (such as http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution#9) if it is not an expression at all? http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution#7.sentence-2 defines evaluation for expressions, but not full-expressions.

Comment: @KrystianS Even though a full-expression might not be an expression, doesn't mean that there necessarily can exist a *"next full-expression to be evaluated"* that isn't an expression.  That said, I'm pretty sure that this does happen if you declare something with a init-declarator right a after an expression. The expression list (if any)  is evaluated just like any expressions, and are part of the full-expression that is the init-declarator.

Comment: Just because not all _full-expressions_ are expressions doesn't mean no _full-expressions_ exist that _are_ expressions and therefore can be evaluated. Good, innit!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Huh, brilliant. One more thing, what does it mean for a full-expression to "include" another expression, does it just mean it will be evaluated when the full-expression is as well?

Comment: @eerorika Would you happen to know :)

Comment: @KrystianS Are you asking about [basic.exec/6](http://eel.is/c%2B%2Bdraft/basic.exec#intro.execution-6) which says that *"The evaluation of a full-expression can include the evaluation of subexpressions"*?

Comment: No, since that isn't normative text, but sure, says the same thing.

Comment: @eerorika Also, going off the example in http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution#5.example-1, specifically in the declaration `S s(1)`, the call comprises of the call to S:S(int), however, does it include the mem-initializer, since its also a full-expression?